# How do I bypass Apple Music on the Music app on Monterey?

Tags: mac, monterey, apple-music, music.app

On Monterey, every time I try to open the `Music` app, it nags me to join `Apple Music`. Moreover, when I open the iTunes store and click to play a song, it nags me again to join Apple Music and does not even allow me to preview a song. No matter how many times I dismiss the nagging ad, it will repeat the ad. Any other options like buying a song are not available. What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I managed to get rid of these ads is to join the Apple Music and then after a few minutes I went to music.apple.com to cancel the subscription. After doing this, I was able again to buy songs and preview songs in the iTunes Store as I usually did on Big Sur and earlier MacOS's.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have Apple Music unticked in preferences? Unticked on mine and never received a nag. It's likely it defaults to ticked on a new install for Apple to maximise exposure.

`Preferences | General | Show: Apple Music`

Comment: Hmmm… It's never nagged me, even though I found that option _was_ ticked (until a few mins ago)! Maybe it's coz I've migrated from iTunes. (Or coz I'm not normally signed in to an Apple ID.)